# Обработка post запроса из js ajax

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Доброго времени суток!

Знатоки, подскажите, в чем проблема - 
При выборе даты в датапикере, я получаю название дня недели, который отправляю пост запросом через функцию :

```
 function getWorkTime(day) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "/getworktime",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: false,
            data: day,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            }
        });
}
```

Далее, пытаюсь принять название дня недели и отправить в модель, которая вернет мне инфу по этому дню:

```
public function getworktimeAction()
   {
       if(isset($_POST)){
                $worktime = worktimeweek::getWorkTimes($_POST);         
                echo json_encode($worktime['starttime'], $worktime['endtime']);

        }

    }
```

Но var_dump($_POST); пустой, подскажите, что я делаю не так?

Причем, если модель получает день недели, то верно возвращает данные.. Вопрос - как принять пост запрос?

```
 public function getworktimeAction()
   {
       $worktime = worktimeweek::getWorkTimes('Пятница');           
                echo json_encode($worktime['starttime'], $worktime['endtime']);


    }
```

Comment: `data: {day: day},` и соответственно извлекать `$_POST['day']`

Comment: А так день выводит function getWorkTime(day) {
        alert(day);
} ?

Comment: @Nsk через консоль выводит название дня, но принять пост не могу, он почему то пуст

Comment: @DmitryKozlov так тоже пусто, если принимать Post['day'] (

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite Post['day'] это опечатка? Должно же быть $_POST['day']

Comment: @LeonidMew да, опечатка, в коде все верно написано.. Пост я все таки получил, но теперь проблема в другом - если я один раз выберу время, то рабочее время отобразится правильно, при повторном выборе другого дня рабочее время остается предыдущим, типа не меняется, видимо, необходимо каким то образом сбросить таймпикер.. хз (